# Implementing custom component decorator in Angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript

In my project I'm currently working on a new design, as I'm working on that new design I still need to keep the old one intact.

I decided that the best solution would be to create for each component a new sass file and code the new design there, and somehow change the `styleUrls` in the `component.ts` file dynamically based on an environment variable

I currently need to create a custom component decorator that would behave exactly like the built-in core `Component` Decorator, but when we create a simple decorator angular can seem not to find the metadata of a in it Component:

```js
export function MyComponent(metadata: Component) {
  return Component(metadata);
}
```

Using in like so gives an error

```
error NG6001: The class 'x' is listed in the declrations of the NgModule ..., but is not a directive, a component or a pipe ...
```

I understand that this is because the Component decorator is not really a simple decorator and basically my component doesn't get the metadata required to act as a component and it doesn't pass angular runtime checks

I tried to find an up-to-date solution to overcome this issue but everything I found was outdated, like this article from 2017:
https://indepth.dev/posts/1163/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular

Is there an up-to-date solution?
or any suggestion on my approach for switching scss file dynamically based on an environment variable?